# Determining an ActiveX control's version in Silverlight or Javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, internet-explorer, activex, version

I am looking for a way to determine

a) whether or not a user has a specific `ActiveX control` installed, and

b) what the `version` of that control is in either `Javascript` or `Silverlight`.

I have used the following `javascript` code to determine the existence of the control:

```
        var activex;
        try {
            activex = new ActiveXObject('SomeProgId');
        } catch(e) {
            activex = null;
        }
        if (activex) {
            alert("found");
        } else {
            alert("not found");
        }
```

And that seems to work just fine.

But I see no way to access any version properties (or any properties at all) from that `activex object`.

I need to know what version the user has in order to determine if they need to be redirected to install a new version?

Any thought on the same are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to get the version information unless it's exposed as a property on the object's interface.

Having said that, you can solve this problem by including a version specifier after the `#version=` in the OBJECT tag's CODEBASE attribute. The object tag will prompt the user to upgrade the control if the version test isn't met.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/941zhks9(v=vs.80).aspx for more details.